# How to enter gasoline costs with 3 decimals?

Tags: gnucash

##### Is there a way we could enter costs associated with gasoline using 3 decimals like the industry uses?

ℰ.ℊ. Suppose there's a $0.374/gallon gasoline tax which is included in the pump price, but can be deducted under certain conditions, so we itemize it separately.  If the pump price of the gasoline is $2.559/gallon, the gasoline expense is actually $2.185/gallon.  Therefore, we'd like to be able to enter something like:

```
2024/01/30   Gas Station,  10.893 gallons @ $2.559
   10.893 gal @ $2.185/gal   Expenses:Auto:Gas         $23.801
   10.893 gal @ $0.374/gal   Expenses:Taxes:Fuel       $ 4.074
                             Liabilities:MasterCard   -$27.88
```

I used this example specifically to show that if the two expenses are added, the total is $27.875, which is rounded up to $27.88, which is the amount the pump charges on the card.  However, without the support of the third decimal, *Gnucash* rounds off to 2 decimals prematurely, giving $23.80 and $4.07 for the expense amounts, which only totals $23.87 and so an imbalance is created.  Wondering how to best address this discrepancy, or if it's even possible.

Comment: Do you have $0.001 in your pocket?

Comment: The exoense was in even cents. The price per unit volume at gave additional digits, as may the actual volume dispensed -- though it's very unlikely you'd be given much more precision on that number.

Comment: "can be deducted under certain conditions, so we itemize it separately. " - if (as I'm guessing) the receipt doesn't show you the tax, how do you decide what value to submit for the deduction? You should use *that* value in gnucash as well, then the actual gas cost is the balance

Comment: @littleadv Yes quite a lot tbh, but can never get enough together for a full cent!  Do you have any lower-right corner pieces? https://i.stack.imgur.com/JRe4Y.png

Comment: @AakashM From the different taxing agencies.  In the USA there's a federal fuel tax (18.4¢/gal for gasoline and 24.4¢/gal for diesel), and then each state has their own fuel taxes, which is 19¢/gal gasoline and 27¢/gal diesel here.  We should probably split those actually into Expenses:Taxes:Federal:Fuel and Expenses:Taxes:State:Fuel or something, that would be $2.004 federal and $2.070 state... but yeah I guess if there's no way to have it work like the pump does, then put the extra penny into the Gas expense, so the tax we recorded in Gnucash matches the deduction we submit at least.

Answer (score 3):

Unless you *really* care about the third decimal, a workaround would be to subtract the gas cost from the total to get the tax instead of calculating the tax.

In that situation your entries would be:

```
2024/01/30   Gas Station,  10.893 gallons @ $2.559
   10.893 gal @ $2.185/gal   Expenses:Auto:Gas         $23.80
   10.893 gal @ $0.374/gal   Expenses:Taxes:Fuel       $ 4.08
                             Liabilities:MasterCard   -$27.88
```

The rounding errors *should* largely even out over multiple transactions.

Comment: Something without rounding errors, that calculates it like the pump, would be best.  What if we have a bunch of 10.893 gallons @ $2.559 or similar transactions?

Comment: Then your total tax would be different from the calculated amount by a few cents. So what?

Answer (score 1):

GNUCash has a set of built‑in currencies that are automatically incorporated *into* the *ledger file* upon first use.
The currencies are identified via a (name space, identifier) tuple, for example [`ISO4217`](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO4217) and `USD`.

1. Create a backup copy of your ledger file.
2. Should you store your ledger in a compressed format, decompress it (e. g. `gunzip` utility).
   (*New* saves are compressed if the *Compress files* check box in Preferences → General → Files is checked)
3. Open the uncompressed file with a text editor such as `vi`.
   (`vim` can automatically compress/decompress `*.gz` files.)
4. Change the embedded currency definition.

   1. Assuming you do not have any other currencies in your ledger, simply search and replace all occurrences of

      ```
      <cmdty:space>ISO4217</cmdty:space>
      ```

      with something else, e. g.

      ```
      <cmdty:space>CURRENCY</cmdty:space>
      ```

      Otherwise (if the `ISO4217`, `USD` tuple remains unchanged) GNUCash *overwrites* the next change with each subsequent save.
   2. Identify the currency definition for the United States Dollar

      ```
      <gnc:commodity version="2.0.0">
        <cmdty:space>CURRENCY</cmdty:space>
        <cmdty:id>USD</cmdty:id>
        <cmdty:get_quotes/>
        <cmdty:quote_source>currency</cmdty:quote_source>
        <cmdty:quote_tz/>
      </gnc:commodity>
      ```

      and insert the following line anywhere in the middle

      ```
        <cmdty:fraction>1000</cmdty:fraction>
      ```
5. Save the change ledger file.
6. Use the ledger from GNUCash.
   Now you can enter and store up to three decimal places from the graphical user interface (GUI).

Frankly, although technically possible, I would not recommend doing this anyway.

Answer (score 0):

You can customise the smallest indivisible unit for a currency or commodity on a per-account basis. In the accounts tree, select/highlight the desired account with a single click, then click "Edit" in the toolbar, then change the value for "Smallest fraction" to the desired power of 10, which in your case will be "1/1000" for both of the two Expense accounts you've mentioned, and "1/100" (or just the default "Use Commodity Value") for the Liabilities account you've mentioned.

The engine will then take care of rounding in the way that you want.

Comment: I have tried doing that before posting [my answer](/a/161584/84649), too. Apparently the problem is that GnuCash rounds entries _individually_ to the _currency’s_ smallest fraction. The `Expenses:Auto:Gas` of `$23.801` gets rounded to `$23.8` and the `Expenses:Taxes:Fuel` of  `$4.074` is rounded to `$4.07` so _GnuCash reports_ just `$27.87`; that is _one cent short_ of the owed amount of `$28.88`. Maybe I did it wrong? I go the whole nine yards with vendors, bills, tax tables, A/P, you name it; perhaps it works fine if you do everything manually.